# Pytorch Lightning - Display per class metrics (precision, recall, f1) in Train.Test(model, datamodule)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

How would i go around adding per-class metrics inside the test_step methods from a Pytorch Lighting Module?

I used

```
    self.f1_each  = F1Score(task="multiclass", num_classes=self.num_classes, average=None )
    self.precision_each  = Precision(task="multiclass", num_classes=self.num_classes, average=None )
    self.recall_each  = Recall(task="multiclass", num_classes=self.num_classes, average=None )
```

In order to compute them. Inside test_step, i've written:

```
def test_step(...):

    class_precisions = self.precision_each(preds, labels)
    class_recalls = self.recall_each(preds, labels)
    class_f1 = self.f1_each(preds, labels)
    for i in range(self.num_classes):
        self.logger.expe(f'precision_{i}', class_precisions[i] , on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log(f'recall_{i}', class_recalls[i] , on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log(f'f1_{i}', class_f1[i] , on_step=False, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
```

However this approach doesn't seem to return the correct values?

Am i doing a mistake? Is there another recommended method?